# Load Page on Click Event

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Ok. I came across a Simple Jquery event where on clicking, it loads a Page on an IFRAME on its respective DIV. 
[**JS Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5orneoc/)

Now, What i actually want to achieve is,

1. instead of using two separate codes classifying them by #frame1, #frame2, i need it to load the events by using the same code

   `showIframe = function (url) {
   document.getElementById('iframetarget').src = url;
   document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block';
   }`
2. On clicking **1** in the liststyle, the corresponding iframe page loads, now on clicking **2** on the liststyle, the corresponding iframe page for **2** loads and the page loaded on **1** is to disappear (or killed, lol)

[**Desired Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tztqsrgj/)

I understand that its not possible to use the same Id in the Div's, so i tried using the `document.getElementByClassName` syntax, but it doesnt work.
Any assistance Please.

Comment: do you accept jquery code? 'cause you put the tag but your code is just pure JS...

Comment: Are you asking this http://jsfiddle.net/rajmathan/hbh4bmy5/ ?

Comment: @Qubex_ , yes Jquery would work too.

Comment: @rajmathan , Oh yes, it is about 80% of what i was looking for. actually, the loading of pages without using #frame1, #frame2 is happening with your code, but it is also loading the page in both the div. actually , when Div 1 is loaded, Div 2 should be empty and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tztqsrgj/6/). Two iframes are connected to the links via data-url value

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe-btn');
for( var i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.getAttribute('data-url');
        var target = this.getAttribute('href').split('#')[1];

        var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        for( var j=0;j<btns.length;j++){
            iframes[j].src='';
        }
        document.getElementById(target).src = url;
        document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block'; 
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jackson, but i noticed the DIVs are using the same Id, wont that be a Problem?
I am gona use numerous amounts of DIvs so giving same Ids would be an issue right

Comment: Yea you are right. I removed the them now. There should never be duplicate ids in the same page. You should only need the ids as a means to link the anchor to the iframe. So where the link has a href of '#iframetarget1', the iframe should have an id of 'iframetarget1'

Comment: Now the Fiddle is not working...lol . the `document.getElementById('frame')` is still being called in the code but in the UI, its not there tho na

Comment: Oops! that line shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks man....now its working...update your Fiddle so i can give Vote up and Correct answer tag :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope fiddle this works! Am using `getelementbyClassName` attribute here..

http://jsfiddle.net/rajmathan/3420cbkt/

HTML Code Follows:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#frame" onclick="showIframe('http://www.uibrush.com/');">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#frame" onclick="showIframe('http://imgur.com/');">&nbsp;2</a></li>
</ul>  

<div id="frame" style="background-color:#9C27B0">
<iframe id='iframetarget' class="full" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript Follows:

```
showIframe = function (url) {

    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('full');
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) { 
  divs[i].src = url;
}

    //document.getElementByClassName('full').src = url;
    document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Css follows:

```
ul{list-style:none;position: fixed;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul li{float:left}
a{text-decoration:none}

.full {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton @rajmathan. this is working :)
If i may insist, can i request one more addition to that code pliz

Comment: @Lemdor Glad its Worked :) Am here to help you.

Comment: Can it be possible to Kill the previous Loaded page upon clicking the event caller. i mean , upon clicking 1, the page loads, upon clicking 2, the page loaded  with 1 is automatically killed, and loads its corresponding page. i dont know if its possible :)

Comment: There is no need of killing the secondary page. As per UI standard, We will not showcase the frame which is not in use. Also, i am using one frame to show which is currently visible. Am i in wrong path?

Comment: actually the presence of two DIVs is a neccessary. The result of your Fiddle code is actually accomplished in my OP given desired Fiddle Demo.

Comment: what i am looking for is along the lines in your first posted fiddle. two DIVs, on clicking, desired page is loaded on its corresponding DIV and the other DIV remains blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71177/discussion-between-rajmathan-and-lemdor).

Answer (score 0):

With jquery code try this

Html

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#frame1" onclick="showIframe('http://www.uibrush.com/');">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#frame2" onclick="showIframe2('http://imgur.com/');">&nbsp;2</a></li>
</ul>
<br><br>


<div id="frame1" style="background-color:#9C27B0">
<iframe id='iframetarget1' class="full" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<br>


<div id="frame2" style="background-color:#ffd800">
<iframe id='iframetarget2' class="full" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#link1").click(showIframe);
$("#link2").click(showIframe);

function showIframe() {
   var target ='#'+ $(this).attr('data-target');
   var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
   $(target).attr('src',url);  
   $(target).parent().css("display:'block'");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q8co5tpe/

Comment: Sensebe , u misunderstood my Query but thanks anyways for the effort. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add event listeners via code e.g.

   $('#element').on('click', function(){ //logic });
2. Every event passes an object to the handler, which holds the executor. You can give the executor some  data-* attributes holding an url or something.

Here some references:

- [Events - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)
- [Data-* MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)